# How to check if element exist or not without using try-catch

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using webdriver with C#, i need to check if element exist or not without using try-catch.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FindElements`. `FindElement` would throw a `NoSuchElementException`. `FindElements` on the other hand returns a empty List. You can check if the list is empty and return null if true.

```
IList<IWebElements> elements = driver.FindElements(By.Id("abcd"));
Assert.True(elements.Count==0, "Field is editable");
```

Answer (score 0):

In js, You can use any find element method like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id('not-there')).then(function(element) {
  alert('Found an element that was not expected to be there!');
}, function(error) {
  alert('The element was not found, as expected');
});
```

Source: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html

In c#, you can do something like this:

```
if(driver.FindElement(By.Id("abc")).size() == 0)
{
return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.

Actually i don't want to catch exception, just to check if element is present if not than it should return null.

Comment: Could you post your C# code so can see what you are attempting to do?

Comment: Hi, Tried above code please see below error:
 Error 1 Non-invocable member 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement.Size' cannot be used like a method. 

Please see below code i am using: int element = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@id='abc']")).Count; Assert.True(element == 0, "Field is editable");